# Bad Compile Error Calling Scala from Java

Tags: java, scala

When I run a working Java class and an incomplete, non-working Scala class the comiler does not say that the error was with the Scala file.

The compiler should say the error is in the Scala class and point to the line number since the program fails at the Scala class, and moreover the error is in the Scala file.

This works as I describe in Java only programs, but not Java with Scala programs.

Why is it not working as expected, and how can I fix this?

EDIT

On further review I found the error location in the messages window, but this is not the Run output.  Many times on a large project there are many files in progress with errors that clutters the message window.  I need this to print the error info in the Run output.  Java does this, why can't Scala?

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: compile_error_test.JavaClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

You can see how with a complex enough program this can lead to time wasted finding the file with the error.

**JavaClass.java**

```
public class JavaClass {

    public void callScalaClass() {

        ScalaClass scalaClass = new ScalaClass();

        scalaClass.scalaTestMethod();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaClass().callScalaClass();
    }

}
```

**ScalaClass.scala**

```
class ScalaClass {

  def scalaTestMethod(): Unit = {

    // Purposefully Undefined
    var nonDefinedVar =

  }

}
```

Comment: under what environment exactly are you trying to compile those files? Could you share more details about the compiling workflow you are using?

Comment: I am using intelliJ, Java 8 and Scala 2.11.  What error msg do you get in your IDE?

Comment: Has no one tried this??

Comment: I tried in IntelliJ IDEA 14 with Scala 2.11 and the compiler reports clearly *"Error:(8, 3) illegal start of simple expression"*, as expected. Are you using SBT or something else? Who is *the compiler* for you exactly?

Comment: @kaktusito Thank You for attempting it.  I am using the libs provided by homebrew.  I am not using SBT.  I do have the incremental option set to IDEA.  Could you post a screenshot of your compiler settings and possibly more info on where you got your compiler from?  Please post as an answer as you may very well have the solution.

Comment: @kaktusito On further review I found the same error you mentioned in the messages, but this is not the Run output.  Many times on a large project there are many files in progress with errors that clutters the message window.  I need this to print the error info in the Run output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was occurring because the files were being compiled but not written to the out directory or any directory for that matter.